# Error connecting to C++ gRPC server from grpc-dotnet: Connect string mismatch: expected 'R' (82) got 'O' (79) at byte 1

Tags: c++, .net, .net-core, grpc

I created a C++ gRPC server using the official example [here](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/examples/cpp/helloworld/greeter_server.cc).

I am trying to consume this server from .NET Core 3.0 using the `grpc-dotnet` libs. I am using grpc++ at the `v1.24.x` (`3e4007e`) branch.

However, when connecting, I get this error on the server:

```
I1022 10:28:38.903132223   24226 timer_generic.cc:738]       TIMER CHECK END: r=1; next=15010
I1022 10:28:38.903143514   24226 timer_manager.cc:188]       sleep for a 1001 milliseconds
I1022 10:28:39.704884424   24227 tcp_server_posix.cc:242]    SERVER_CONNECT: incoming connection: ipv4:127.0.0.1:35425
D1022 10:28:39.704922757   24227 tcp_posix.cc:1253]          cannot set inq fd=11 errno=92
I1022 10:28:39.704957089   24227 timer_generic.cc:365]       TIMER 0x7ffa640017a8: SET 134812 now 14812 call 0x7ffa640017d8[0x7ffa78ab7210]
I1022 10:28:39.704970089   24227 timer_generic.cc:401]         .. add to shard 9 with queue_deadline_cap=15009 => is_first_timer=false
I1022 10:28:39.704983130   24227 handshaker.cc:131]          handshake_manager 0x7ffa640016f0: error="No Error" shutdown=0 index=0, args={endpoint=0x7ffa640011b0, args=0x7ffa640019b0 {size=2: grpc.primary_user_agent=grpc-c++/1.24.2, grpc.compression_enabled_algorithms_bitset=15}, read_buffer=0x7ffa64001a10 (length=0), exit_early=0}
I1022 10:28:39.705019588   24227 handshaker.cc:164]          handshake_manager 0x7ffa640016f0: handshaking complete -- scheduling on_handshake_done with error="No Error"
I1022 10:28:39.705031005   24227 timer_generic.cc:467]       TIMER 0x7ffa640017a8: CANCEL pending=true
I1022 10:28:39.705065212   24227 timer_generic.cc:365]       TIMER 0x7ffa64003648: SET 7214812 now 14812 call 0x7ffa640035a8[0x7ffa78aff900]
I1022 10:28:39.705076629   24227 timer_generic.cc:401]         .. add to shard 7 with queue_deadline_cap=15009 => is_first_timer=false
I1022 10:28:39.705088003   24227 bdp_estimator.h:53]         bdp[ipv4:127.0.0.1:35425]:sched acc=0 est=65536
I1022 10:28:39.705113295   24227 chttp2_transport.cc:839]    W:0x7ffa64001f00 SERVER [ipv4:127.0.0.1:35425] state IDLE -> WRITING [TRANSPORT_FLOW_CONTROL]
I1022 10:28:39.705126336   24227 chttp2_transport.cc:839]    W:0x7ffa64001f00 SERVER [ipv4:127.0.0.1:35425] state WRITING -> WRITING+MORE [INITIAL_WRITE]
I1022 10:28:39.705137711   24227 init.cc:164]                grpc_init(void)
I1022 10:28:39.705183127   24227 chttp2_transport.cc:1900]   perform_transport_op[t=0x7ffa64001f00]: ON_CONNECTIVITY_STATE_CHANGE:p=0x7ffa640042e0:from=IDLE SET_ACCEPT_STREAM:0x7ffa78aeeaa0(0x7ffa64004278,...)
I1022 10:28:39.705194418   24227 timer_generic.cc:365]       TIMER 0x7ffa640018a8: SET 134812 now 14812 call 0x7ffa640018d8[0x7ffa78b6b670]
I1022 10:28:39.705229459   24227 timer_generic.cc:401]         .. add to shard 6 with queue_deadline_cap=15009 => is_first_timer=false
I1022 10:28:39.705265667   24227 connectivity_state.cc:100]  CONWATCH: 0x7ffa640021a8 server_transport: from IDLE [cur=READY] notify=0x7ffa640042e0
I1022 10:28:39.705322666   24227 chttp2_transport.cc:1900]   perform_transport_op[t=0x7ffa64001f00]: ON_CONNECTIVITY_STATE_CHANGE:p=0x7ffa640042e0:from=READY
I1022 10:28:39.705334041   24227 timer_generic.cc:467]       TIMER 0x7ffa64003648: CANCEL pending=true
I1022 10:28:39.705345415   24227 tcp_posix.cc:265]           TCP:0x7ffa640011b0 notify_on_read
I1022 10:28:39.705356748   24227 connectivity_state.cc:100]  CONWATCH: 0x7ffa640021a8 server_transport: from READY [cur=READY] notify=0x7ffa640042e0
I1022 10:28:39.705368123   24227 timer_generic.cc:365]       TIMER 0x7ffa64003648: SET 7214812 now 14812 call 0x7ffa640035a8[0x7ffa78aff900]
I1022 10:28:39.705379456   24227 timer_generic.cc:401]         .. add to shard 7 with queue_deadline_cap=15009 => is_first_timer=false
D1022 10:28:39.705402123   24227 flow_control.cc:113]        0x7ffa64003368[0][svr] | t updt sent | trw:                         65535, tlw:                       4194304, taw:              65535 -> 4194304, srw:                              , slw:                              , saw:                              
I1022 10:28:39.705433539   24227 writing.cc:116]             SERVER: Ping sent [ipv4:127.0.0.1:35425]: 2/2
I1022 10:28:39.705447205   24227 chttp2_transport.cc:839]    W:0x7ffa64001f00 SERVER [ipv4:127.0.0.1:35425] state WRITING+MORE -> WRITING [begin write in current thread]
I1022 10:28:39.705460205   24227 tcp_posix.cc:1058]          WRITE 0x7ffa640011b0 (peer=ipv4:127.0.0.1:35425)
D1022 10:28:39.705495954   24227 tcp_posix.cc:1062]          DATA: 00 00 18 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 04 00 40 00 00 00 05 00 40 00 00 00 06 00 00 20 00 fe 03 00 00 00 01 '............@.....@...... .......'
I1022 10:28:39.705507371   24227 tcp_posix.cc:1058]          WRITE 0x7ffa640011b0 (peer=ipv4:127.0.0.1:35425)
D1022 10:28:39.705538287   24227 tcp_posix.cc:1062]          DATA: 00 00 04 08 00 00 00 00 00 00 3f 00 01 00 00 08 06 00 00 00 00 00 00 '..........?............'
I1022 10:28:39.705549662   24227 tcp_posix.cc:1058]          WRITE 0x7ffa640011b0 (peer=ipv4:127.0.0.1:35425)
D1022 10:28:39.705561036   24227 tcp_posix.cc:1062]          DATA: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 '.......'
I1022 10:28:39.705593577   24227 tcp_posix.cc:1096]          write: "No Error"
I1022 10:28:39.705604952   24227 chttp2_transport.cc:2660]   ipv4:127.0.0.1:35425: Start BDP ping err="No Error"
I1022 10:28:39.705616327   24227 timer_generic.cc:467]       TIMER 0x7ffa64003648: CANCEL pending=true
I1022 10:28:39.705627660   24227 bdp_estimator.h:66]         bdp[ipv4:127.0.0.1:35425]:start acc=0 est=65536
I1022 10:28:39.705650451   24227 chttp2_transport.cc:839]    W:0x7ffa64001f00 SERVER [ipv4:127.0.0.1:35425] state WRITING -> IDLE [finish writing]
I1022 10:28:39.705674784   24227 timer_generic.cc:365]       TIMER 0x7ffa64003648: SET 7214812 now 14812 call 0x7ffa640035a8[0x7ffa78aff900]
I1022 10:28:39.705686117   24227 timer_generic.cc:401]         .. add to shard 7 with queue_deadline_cap=15009 => is_first_timer=false
I1022 10:28:39.732094959   24227 tcp_posix.cc:605]           TCP:0x7ffa640011b0 got_read: "No Error"
I1022 10:28:39.732152375   24227 tcp_posix.cc:590]           TCP:0x7ffa640011b0 alloc_slices
I1022 10:28:39.732163750   24227 resource_quota.cc:889]      RQ anonymous_pool_7ffa64000fb0 ipv4:127.0.0.1:35425: alloc 8192; free_pool -> -8192
I1022 10:28:39.732175166   24227 resource_quota.cc:321]      RQ: check allocation for user 0x7ffa640014a0 shutdown=0 free_pool=-8192
I1022 10:28:39.732186499   24227 resource_quota.cc:347]      RQ anonymous_pool_7ffa64000fb0 ipv4:127.0.0.1:35425: grant alloc 8192 bytes; rq_free_pool -> 9223372036854767615
I1022 10:28:39.732197832   24227 tcp_posix.cc:571]           TCP:0x7ffa640011b0 read_allocation_done: "No Error"
I1022 10:28:39.732209207   24227 tcp_posix.cc:401]           TCP:0x7ffa640011b0 call_cb 0x7ffa64002040 0x7ffa78b01360:0x7ffa64001f00
I1022 10:28:39.732222165   24227 tcp_posix.cc:404]           READ 0x7ffa640011b0 (peer=ipv4:127.0.0.1:35425) error="No Error"
D1022 10:28:39.732271497   24227 tcp_posix.cc:410]           DATA: 50 4f 53 54 20 2f 64 69 63 6f 6d 2e 44 69 63 6f 6d 2f 53 61 79 48 65 6c 6c 6f 20 48 54 54 50 2f 31 2e 31 0d 0a 48 6f 73 74 3a 20 31 32 37 2e 30 2e 30 2e 31 3a 35 30 30 35 31 0d 0a 55 73 65 72 2d 41 67 65 6e 74 3a 20 67 72 70 63 2d 64 6f 74 6e 65 74 2f 32 2e 32 34 2e 30 2e 30 0d 0a 54 45 3a 20 74 72 61 69 6c 65 72 73 0d 0a 67 72 70 63 2d 61 63 63 65 70 74 2d 65 6e 63 6f 64 69 6e 67 3a 20 69 64 65 6e 74 69 74 79 2c 67 7a 69 70 0d 0a 54 72 61 6e 73 66 65 72 2d 45 6e 63 6f 64 69 6e 67 3a 20 63 68 75 6e 6b 65 64 0d 0a 43 6f 6e 74 65 6e 74 2d 54 79 70 65 3a 20 61 70 70 6c 69 63 61 74 69 6f 6e 2f 67 72 70 63 0d 0a 0d 0a 35 0d 0a 00 00 00 00 0f 0d 0a 46 0d 0a 0a 0d 47 72 65 65 74 65 72 43 6c 69 65 6e 74 0d 0a 'POST /dicom.Dicom/SayHello HTTP/1.1..Host: 127.0.0.1:50051..User-Agent: grpc-dotnet/2.24.0.0..TE: trailers..grpc-accept-encoding: identity,gzip..Transfer-Encoding: chunked..Content-Type: application/grpc....5.........F....GreeterClient..'
I1022 10:28:39.732354288   24227 chttp2_transport.cc:2866]   transport 0x7ffa64001f00 set connectivity_state=4
I1022 10:28:39.732365662   24227 connectivity_state.cc:147]  SET: 0x7ffa640021a8 server_transport: READY --> SHUTDOWN [close_transport]
I1022 10:28:39.732377037   24227 connectivity_state.cc:160]  NOTIFY: 0x7ffa640021a8 server_transport: 0x7ffa640042e0
I1022 10:28:39.732388370   24227 timer_generic.cc:467]       TIMER 0x7ffa64003648: CANCEL pending=true
I1022 10:28:39.732433744   24227 chttp2_transport.cc:1900]   perform_transport_op[t=0x7ffa64001f00]: SET_ACCEPT_STREAM:(nil)((nil),...)
I1022 10:28:39.732467744   24227 tcp_posix.cc:854]           TCP:0x7ffa640011b0 got_error: {"created":"@1571754519.732422411","description":"FD Shutdown","file":"src/core/lib/iomgr/lockfree_event.cc","file_line":194,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1571754519.732342913","description":"Failed parsing HTTP/2","file":"src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/transport/chttp2_transport.cc","file_line":2582,"grpc_status":14,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1571754519.732294330","description":"Connect string mismatch: expected 'R' (82) got 'O' (79) at byte 1","file":"src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/transport/parsing.cc","file_line":97}]}]}
I1022 10:28:39.732498535   24227 chttp2_transport.cc:2676]   ipv4:127.0.0.1:35425: Complete BDP ping err={"created":"@1571754519.732342913","description":"Failed parsing HTTP/2","file":"src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/transport/chttp2_transport.cc","file_line":2582,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1571754519.732294330","description":"Connect string mismatch: expected 'R' (82) got 'O' (79) at byte 1","file":"src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/transport/parsing.cc","file_line":97}]}
I1022 10:28:39.732521285   24227 init.cc:211]                grpc_shutdown(void)
I1022 10:28:39.732532618   24227 resource_quota.cc:547]      RU shutdown 0x7ffa640014a0
I1022 10:28:39.902870280   24226 timer_manager.cc:204]       wait ended: was_timed:1 kicked:0
```

Here is my .NET 3.0 project.

```cs
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Grpc.Net.Client;
using Dicom;

namespace Client
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress("http://127.0.0.1:50051");
            var client = new Dicom.Dicom.DicomClient(channel);

            var reply = await client.SayHelloAsync(new HelloRequest { Name = "GreeterClient" });
            Console.WriteLine("Greeting: " + reply.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Protobuf Include="../../../proto/dicom.proto" GrpcServices="Client" Link="Protos\dicom.proto" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Google.Protobuf" Version="3.10.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Grpc.Net.Client" Version="2.24.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Grpc.Tools" Version="2.24.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Also, here is my proto file:

```
syntax = "proto3";

package dicom;

// The greeting service definition.
service Dicom {
  // Sends a greeting
  rpc SayHello (HelloRequest) returns (HelloReply);
  rpc SayHellos (HelloRequest) returns (stream HelloReply);
}

// The request message containing the user's name.
message HelloRequest {
  string name = 1;
}

// The response message containing the greetings
message HelloReply {
  string message = 1;
}
```

**UPDATE**: I changed to using the .NET libraries from the original gRPC team, and it works. Here is the new server-side logs (from C++) in an effort to debug the issue.

https://pastebin.com/cSWNhVvT

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is you need to set an AppContext flag when using `http`:

```cs
// This switch must be set before creating the GrpcChannel/HttpClient.
AppContext.SetSwitch(
    "System.Net.Http.SocketsHttpHandler.Http2UnencryptedSupport", true);
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/troubleshoot?view=aspnetcore-3.0#call-insecure-grpc-services-with-net-core-client